# How can I create a "Virtual Smart Card" on my TPM without joining my Windows computer to a Domain?

Tags: windows, openvpn, certificate, windows-server, smartcard

I want to store a OpenVPN client certificates on our laptops secured by my TPM, so that the certificate can't be stolen/extracted from the laptop even with admin rights.

Microsoft offeres "[Virtual Smartcards](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/virtual-smart-cards/virtual-smart-card-use-virtual-smart-cards)" that use the TPM.  I should be able to access them via [PKCS11 from the OpenVPN client.config](https://acksyn.org/docs/smart-cards-openvpn.html). There are [CAPI to PKCS11 libraries/adapters](https://github.com/risacher/p11-capi).

I can create a virtual smart card reader using this command:

```
tpmvscmgr.exe create /name OpenVPN1 /pin prompt /pinpolicy minlen 4 maxlen 8 /adminkey random /generate
```

This works. However now I need a way to actually generate a public/private key and certificate signing request, that I can sign on my openssl CA.

However Microsoft in their [tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/virtual-smart-cards/virtual-smart-card-get-started) wants you to connect the computer to a domain with a domain controller. And create a "certificate template" on the domain controller. I don't want/need this. I am not using the Microsoft CA. I have a separate openssl CA.

Is there a way to create a public/private key pair without joining the laptop to a domain?

Comment: I think the important point here is that the private key must never leave the TPM. As such, the TPM must generate the private key and the CSR.

Comment: @DanielB: The question is how can it be done? Can you provide the commands to generate a 2048bit key pair on the TPM backed Virtual Smart card? I don't want to join the machines to a Domain but the Microsoft guides assume that as a precondition.

Comment: No, I can’t. Try some OpenSSL PKCS11 stuff from around the net. You misunderstand though: It’s just the Windows cert GUI that depends on domain membership. Not the process itself.

Comment: @DanielB I know there no technical reason why it should not work without domain membership. But I am struggling to find a practical way how to actually do it. I did some more research today, but there is not a lot of information on the web on this topic and I was hoping maybe somebody here has the answer. If I find a way I will post an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to answer my own question:

I didn't find a way to create a keypair on the smartcard directly. But you can import one. And it will be locked in the Virtual Smartcard from that point on (keys will be `neverExtract`).

First create the smartcard (reader) as per the question with
`tpmvscmgr.exe create /name OpenVPN1 /pin prompt /pinpolicy minlen 4 maxlen 8 /adminkey random /generate` as Admin.

Now `certutil -scinfo` will show the virtual reader, but will fail showing the certificate, because there is none yet.

In order to proceed you need a combined pkcs12 file. You can create your client keypair off TPM and sign them as usual by your CA e.g. with openssl. If you have the resulting files as separte .key and .crt you may combine them with OpenSSL using e.g.
`“C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl" pkcs12 -export -out client.pfx -inkey client.key -in client.crt` Be sure to securely wipe those files off your storage once you have them imported into your Virtual Smartcard.

Then you can import it into the Virtual Smartcard with `certutil`.
Run `certutil -csp "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider" -importpfx client.pfx`
Be aware that the order of arguments matters: `-importpfx` has to be provided last.

Now `certutil -scinfo` will show the certificate.

PS: OpenVPN for Windows is by default compiled without PKCS11 support. But it works directly with CAPI.

Remove `cert client.crt` and `key client.key` and instead provide `cryptoapicert "THUMB:371f180ba80234845a93b116ea02e5222dffad1e"` in your OpenVPN `client.conf`. Where 371f180ba80234845a93b116ea02e5222dffad1e should be replaced with the fingerprint of your own client certificate. You find your certificate fingerprint in the output of `certutil -scinfo` after `Cert:`.

Unfortunately Microsoft's Virtual Smartcard does not support `RSA-PSS` yet which is required for TLS 1.3 and used by recent OpenVPN with TLS 1.2 too. OpenVPN currently does not detect that it is not available and fails ( https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/1296 ) when trying to use it. If this is still unpatched by either MS or OpenVPN you have to use an older OpenVPN version 2.4.8 as a workaround.

Comment: Possible solution for on TPM key generation: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/179422/37064
However some old TPMs suffer from weak private key generation, so proceed with caution ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROCA_vulnerability )